# Debugging of Angular app created with "dotnet new angular" is not working in VSCode

Tags: angular, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code

Angular code debugging should be straight forward according to the documentation for "Debugger for Chrome" VSCode extension.

However I cannot make it work.

I created a simple default app using `dotnet new angular -o Homepage`, which is an Web API + Angular ASP.NET Core project.

I installed the extension and configured launch.json to trigger the debug:

```
"configurations": [
{
   "name": "Launch Chrome",
   "request": "launch",
   "type": "chrome",
   "url": "http://localhost:5001",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
{
    "name": "Attach to Chrome",
    "port": 9222,
    "request": "attach",
    "type": "chrome",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

When executed with `dotnet run` command, browser opens and runs the application on port 5001.

Then in VSCode I selected Debug, then selected "Launch Chrome" option and clicked the debug button (the green arrow button), a new browser window opened, but breakpoints that I set in the angular app which is ClientApp don't get hit in VSCode.

Also I tried to use the "attach" option for debugging, previously I added "chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222" for Chrome shortcut. Ran the app as before, then selected "Attach to Chrome" option for debugging and clicked the debug button. This also didn't work, no breakpoints get hit.

What am I doing wrong or what's the trick here, why isn't it working?
It is exactly as the documentation for "Debugger for Chrome" extension instructs to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below the steps, that are needed to get started with the debugging:

- Open the `ClientApp` root in `VS Code`.

[image]

- Make sure that `Debugger for Chrome` extension is installed.
- Run `npm run start` to serve the application. By default it will be served on `http://localhost:4200/`.
- Hit `F5` and choose `Chrome` to generate a default `launch.json`.

[image]

- In `launch.json` update the port to `4200`

its content should look following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Put a breakpoint in the `AppComponent` to the `title` variable.
- Hit F5, the breakpoint should be hit.

[image]

In your case, the issue can be that the application was not served by the Angular CLI. (`ng serve` was not called using `npm run start`.) The server on port `5001` is the `.NET` based backend, the `Debugger for Chrome` is not able to cooperate with that by default.

Another issue can be that `VS Code` was not opened from the root of the Angular application. The default `launch.json` settings contains `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"`, so if the `VS Code` is opened for example from the root of the .NET application, the breakpoints won't be hit.